Quantifiers with restricted domain

Screenshot from Discrete Math Rosen Textbook.

Note that the restriction of a universal quantification is the same as the universal quantification of a conditional statement. For instance, ∀x < 0 ($x^{2}$ > 0) is another way of expressing ∀x(x < 0 → $x^{2}$ > 0). On the other hand, the restriction of an existential quantification is the same as the existential quantification of a conjunction. For instance, ∃z > 0 ($z^{2}$ = 2) is another way of expressing ∃z(z > 0 ∧ $z^{2}$ = 2).

Why couldn't we also make it that the restriction of an existential quantification is the same as the existential quantification of a conditional statement?
For example like here: Why can't ∃z > 0 ($z^{2}$ = 2) be equivalent to ∃z(z > 0 --> $z^{2}$ = 2)?
Kindly please let me know.

Have you tried to see what gives the negation. The negation of a conditional is not a conditional.

@hamam_Abdallah kindly could you please elaborate?

@hamam_Abdallah I'm not fully seeing how the negation helps in this question.

$not ( not P)=P$ .

@hamam_Abdallah Sorry still not following. I edited my question to further clarify. Here's what I added: why can't ∃z > 0 ($z^{2}$ = 2) be equivalent to ∃z(z > 0 --> $z^{2}$ = 2)?

The universal quantifier can be vacuously true, which means that if there is no $x$ such that $x<0$, then it would be true that $\forall x<0 (x^2 >0)$. So this quantifier is saying: "if there is an $x$ such that $x<0$, then that would imply that $x^2 >0$". It may be helpful to note that the implication $\alpha \rightarrow \beta$ is equivalent to $\neg \alpha \lor \beta $.
On the other hand, the existential quantifier demands the existance of at least one $z>0$, and furthermore, it demands that for at least one of those $z$, it must hold that $z^2 = 2$. Hence, we need to satisfy both conditions simultaneously.

Ok I think I see! Ya so even though in this case we know there exists z > 0, if we selected an empty restricted domain, then the existential quantification would be automatically false since there doesn't "exist" any element in the domain that satisfies the predicate. Is that what you're getting at?

That is correct.

Awesome! Thank you so much!
